# Settting the ClickOnce installation folder URL in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

In [Visual Studio 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012) I'm trying to create an installer on my [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) project. In the projects properties under publish, *Installation Folder URL* does not accept an absolute path. I want to install the program to a path I predefined, but it installs it under:

```
C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\71530DHX.EQT\HX2K7H9Z.BVH\i..tion_adf38724ab9c7a8b_0001.0000_dac8e5c01327591a
```

How can I specify an install location like `C:\MyApplication`?

Comment: Please post your second question to an entirely different question as it deserves its own space and is unrelated to this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for ClickOnce to manage the caching of your application including handling updates, it will put it under the AppData folder.  You will not be able to install it a folder of your choosing. It's the nature of the beast.

Normally this isn't a big deal.  You can still create a desktop icon for the user to access your program (if that was your concern):

[image]