# Changing the install directory for a C# program in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installation

I am kind of new to Visual Studio and have found no solutions online, so this may be a simple problem nobody has bothered to post about.

I am working with a system that requires certain browser settings on a very specific version of Internet Explorer and am trying to create a launcher that can be installed on all users of a domain computer that establishes all these settings and creates a simple IE window (to dissuade people from using it more than needed).

I have written this application, but when I run the installer it a) gives me no option to change the install directory, and b) does not give me the option to change the default install directory in the project properties.

Other sources continue to say to change the 'Install Folder URL' to something else, but whenever I change it to say '\\localhost\c$\A_File_Directory', nothing ever changes and it continues to install in an unknown location.

Any help would be appreciated (perhaps a location with in-depth examples for VS)

EDIT -- It seems there is no way to do what I am looking for through Visual Studio, so I think I will be just deploying the ClickOnce installer through Group Policy so it can run on a per-user basis. Thanks to all who helped!

Comment: What installer are you using?

Comment: I believe it is the standard ClickOnce Installer. I would change it to the Windows Installer, but there does not seem to be an option.

Comment: see [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c37e68bc.aspx), and [a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217037/settting-the-clickonce-installation-folder-url-in-visual-studio-2012).

Comment: I have looked at the first one, and both outline the problem, but do not solve it. Is there a way to change it from the ClickOnce installer? I feel like I'm not the only one who would want multiple users to have access to a program I write and install on a computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of VS 2010 the ClickOnce Installer does not let you choose where to install the application.  It controls that.  I have found it rather irritating and if you really need to control where something is installed you need to use a different installer.

Here's another answer for VS 2012
[Settting the ClickOnce installation folder URL in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217037/settting-the-clickonce-installation-folder-url-in-visual-studio-2012)